# RAII: do mutexes in a vector declared in a loop all unlock in the next iteration?

Tags: c++, mutex, raii, stdmutex

Suppose I have the following:

```
// ... necessary includes

class X {
    struct wrapper{ std::mutex mut{}; }
    std::array<wrapper, 20> wrappers{};

    void Y() 
    {
        for (auto i{0u}; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            std::vector<std::unique_lock<std::mutex>> locks_arr{};
            for (auto& wrapp : wrappers)
            {
                locks.emplace_back(std::unique_lock{wrapp.mut});
            }

            // are the mutexes in locks_arr unlocked here by RAII,
            // because locks_arr goes 'out of scope'?
            if (/* some condition */) continue; 
            
            // do some other long stuff
            // end of loop iteration; how about here? 
        }
    }
}
```

A straightforward question, elucidated in the code itself. Do the mutex locks in `locks_arr` unlock in the next iteration of the loop, or is there an explicit need to unlock all the mutexes one by one in both the `if` statement block, and at the end of the outer `for`-loop?

Comment: Why are you making something simple complicated? Remove all the mutexes and arrays and focus on the relevant part of your question, lifetime of objects. A local variable is destroyed at the end of it's scope. What part of that is unclear to you?

Comment: @user17732522 and @super, I was under the impression that `continue` also implicitly 'ends the scope', because it short-circuits the rest of the loop execution and goes to the next iteration (thereby destroying the vector of locks). The complication is precisely because wanted to clarify this *particular* scenario, and check my understanding of scope and object destruction.

Comment: @SRSR333 I misread your question initially.

Comment: When the `vector` goes out of scope, its contents will go out of scope. If the content's destructor does something fun like release a mutex, that mutex will be released. A simpler experiment would be a `vector` full of a custom class that prints diagnostic messages on construction, destruction, copies, assignments, moves, etc... so you can see the whole picture.

Comment: @SRSR333 Yes, that's correct. I still don't see how the mutexes and vector is relevant to that *particular scenario*. It works the same for a single `int`, or any local object. My point was just that unrelevant details just makes your question harder to understand.

Comment: @super, I am implementing a data structure (a concurrent skip list), and at some point, this particular scenario arose. I attempted to pare down as much irrelevant detail as possible already; any further and I feel I would have lost the essence of the question.

Comment: Have a look at [ask]. One of the main ideas behind asking a good question is to make it minimal. Asking when a scope ends is a very legit question. What I'm repeatedly trying to point out to you is only the fact that `vector`s and `mutex`es plays no part in that question. Scope behaves the same no matter what object it is. The only thing that inclusion contributes to here is making it more unclear what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question—yes, this is how RAII works. The vector is declared inside the body of the `for` loop; it is destroyed and recreated every iteration. `continue` also causes the execution of the rest of the loop to be short-circuited.

When the vector is destructed, every object it contains is also destroyed. As such, the destructor of `unique_lock` is called, which unlocks the mutexes.